# jquery inputmask not accepting quantifier on validator function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to make a customAlias to use with jQuery Inputmask, but i'm facing the following problem:

**My input:**

`<input id="input-field-nome" data-inputmask="'alias':'customAlias'" type="text" data-rule-required="true" class="form-control required" placeholder="Nome e sobrenome">`

**And on my JS:**

```
 Inputmask.extendAliases({
    'customAlias': {
      autoUnmask: true,
      placeholder: "",
      mask: "a",
      definitions: { "a" : { validator: "[a-zA-Z]+" } }
    }
  });

  //initializing the plugin
  $(":input").inputmask({
    placeholder: ''
  });
```

I understood that the option `validator: "[a-zA-Z]+"` should work as: 'any alphabetical character **one or more times**, but the quantifier `+` isn't working. I'm only able to insert one letter in the input.

I've tried the following regexes but none of them worked:

`"validator": "[a-zA-Z\+]",` - I saw something like this on RobinHerbots' examples.

`"validator": "[a-zA-Z]\+",` - I thought that escaping the `+` would solve the problem. (fail).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(":input").inputmask('Regex', { 
    regex: "^[a-zA-Z]+"
});
```

and add jquery.inputmask.bundle.js to your project.

you can use [bower](http://bower.io/) to include it by this command line

```
bower install jquery.inputmask
```

This is my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/aissa1989/cfee7q8r/)

Comment: It isn't working properly. In your example, it's possible to add any type of characters.

Comment: Your question is to create input mask to accept only alphabetic characters,no?

Comment: Yes. I mean, in your fiddle, isn't working correctly.

Comment: Can you give me an example,what type of character you want in input form? Because for me it  work correctly.

Comment: is that what you want?
Example 1 : azertyuAZERDFS
and not that
Example 2 : aze1458&é"'&:rtyuAZERDFS